# Scan file contents into an array of a structure

Tags: c, file-io, eof

I have a structure in my program that contains a particular array. I want to scan a random file with numbers and put the contents into that array.

This is my code : ( NOTE : This is a sample from a bigger program, so I need the structure and arrays as declared )

The contents of the file are basically : 5 4 3 2 5 3 4 2

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define first 500
#define sec 500


struct trial{
  int f;
  int r;
  float what[first][sec];
};

int trialtest(trial *test);

main(){
  trial test;
  trialtest(&test);
}

int trialtest(trial *test){
  int z,x,i;
  FILE *fin;
  fin=fopen("randomfile.txt","r"); 
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",(*test).what[z][x]);
    }
  fclose(fin);
  return 0;
}
```

But the problem is, whenever this I run this code, I get this error :
[image]

**(25) : warning 508 - Data of type 'double' supplied where a pointer is required**

I tried adding

```
do{
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
      q=fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",(*test).what[z][x]);
    }
  }while(q!=EOF);
```

But that didnt work either, it gives the same error.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression: `(*test).what[z][x]` is a `float` in the array (which gets promoted to a `double`, thus the warning message). `fscanf()` needs to get a **pointer** to the data (in this case a `float`), so that it can write to it. You need to change this line to:

```
q=fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",&(*test).what[z][x]);
```

As a side note, accessing the member of a `struct` through a pointer to that `struct` is so common that you have a special `->` operator in C to do just that. So instead of `(*foo).bar` you can write `foo->bar`.

So the line becomes a slightly more readable:

```
q=fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",&test->what[z][x]);
```

Comment: Voted best since its more informative, thank you both guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to **read** the value of what[z][x] instead of referencing it:

```
fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",(*test).what[z][x]);
```

Try this:

```
fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",&((*test).what[z][x]));
```

Or,

```
fscanf(fin,"%5.2f\t",&(test->what[z][x]));
```

Comment: Both `.` and `->` operators have a higher precedence than the "address of" `&` operator. So you don't need the extra parenthesis.

Comment: Such a simple error that I couldnt figure out . Thank you thank you thank you :)